# Windows upgrade from 8 to 10

Tags: windows, upgrade

I'd like to install Windows 10 on fresh Computer with Windows 8 installed and legally activated.

Can I upgrade to 10 without having to upgrade to Windows 8.1 beforehand (downloading 3.5Go for 8.1 is an issue) and still benefit from the one year free activation?

Comment: Wrong website, check out SuperUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windows 10 is only available for windows 8.1 and windows 7 systems.
you will need to upgrade to 8.1 first.